# In UDS, is it possible to configure security access to unlock a session?

Tags: can-bus, diagnostics, autosar, automotive

1. I have 4 sessions namely Default, Extended, Programming and Supplier session.
2. The jump to supplier session will happen via extended session. Default -> Extended -> Supplier
3. But before jumping to Supplier session I need to provide security access.
4. Once the security access is provided then only the jump should happen to Supplier session.

As per the ISO 14229 - 1 document the security access service is NOT applicable in default session but it is APPLICABLE in Non-Default session. So does it mean security access can be applied between 2 non-default session?

Comment: I dont think this really belongs in StackOverflow...

Answer (score 1):

You can configure security level basically for every diagnostic service, even subservice (like for specific DIDs). What I understand you want to do is to require security level for changing into Supplier session, which is definitely possible to configure.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, There is no security level required to enter any session.
To perform any action in any session other than default, we need security level.
Example : 
1. To execute any service
2. To Read/write a DID